# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

The code I have below works.  It's pulls in a list of every item in my One Repository.

When I add my second table to pull all the items out of THAT table I get the following error, on my DataTwo I can't figure out why it's throwing this error as the first one is programmed the exact same way.

"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name"

**View Model**

```
public IList<OneVM> Ones { get; set; }
public IList<TwoVM> Twos { get; set; }
public ViewModelVM()
{
    this.Ones = new List<OneVM>();
    this.Twos = new List<TwoVM>();
}
```

**Working Original Code Below (Controller)**

```
public ActionResult Directory()
{
    var vm = new ViewModelVM();
    var datas = _OneRepository.GetData();
    vm.Datas = _mapper.Map<IList<DataVM>>(datas.OrderBy(i => i.Name)); 
    return View(vm);
}
```

**Desired Broken Code Below (Controller)**

```
    public ActionResult Directory()
    {
 var vm = new FormDirectoryVM();
            var datas = _OneRepository.GetData();
            var datasTwo= _TwoRepository.GetMoreData();
            vm.Datas = _mapper.Map<IList<DataVM>>(datas.OrderBy(i => i.Name)); 
        return View(vm);
            vm.DatasTwo= _mapper.Map<IList<DataTwoVM>>(datasTwo);
return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: `_OneRepository.GetData().AsEnumerable().Concat(_TwoRepository.GetMoreData());`

Comment: I am afraid this gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my Repository. I was including something that didn't need to be.

```
 public IEnumerable<Two> GetMoreData()
        {
            return _context.Twos
                .Include(i => i.Title) // I don't need this line
                .Include(i => i.Description) // I don't need this line either
                .Include(i => i.Keywords)
                .Include(j => j.Text) // Or this Line
                .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)
             ;
        }
```